# Show data according to condition sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get it some filed using OrderBy condition but in my scenario orderby not working. In here my `ProductSequence` is `int` filed.

```
IList<ProViewModels> _newprd = iproRepository
  .GetList(x => x.ProductId.Equals(ProductId))
  .Select(x => new ProViewModels { ProductName = x.ProductName, DisplayName = x.DisplayName })
  .OrderBy(x => x.ProOrder)
  .ToList();

return _newprd;
```

Comment: What "not working means"? What's the actual problem?

Comment: What is not working with the orderby? What results do you expect and what results do you receive (you don't have to add the results to the question, only the differences you noticed and are relevant for the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your repository you get a list of `Products`. Using `Select` you transform your list of `Products` to a list of `ProViewModels`. For your transformation you do not spezify the `ProOrder` property of `ProViewModels`, so the default value will be used.

Basically that means that your list gets ordered but the value they get ordered by is the same for all instances in the collection.